# Proving continuity using properties of rationals and irrationals

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

**Given:**

$r \ge 1 $

$f_r(x) = 1/(q^r)$ if $x=p/q$ in lowest terms, and $x \neq 0$

$f_r(x) = 0$ if $x=0$ or $x$ is irrational

**Problem:**

Show that $f_r(x)$ is continuous at the irrational numbers

**My attempt:**

For any irrational $\alpha $, I want to show that $\lim_{x\to \alpha}f_r(x)=f_r(\alpha)$

i.e. $\forall \epsilon \gt 0,$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that if $|x-\alpha|\lt\delta$ then $|f_r(x)-f_r(\alpha)|\lt\epsilon$

Want: $|f_r(x)-f_r(\alpha)|\lt\epsilon$

$\alpha$ is irrational so $f_r(\alpha)=0$ so I want $|f_r(x)|\lt\epsilon$

If x is irrational, then $f_r(x)=0$ so clearly this is less than $\epsilon$

If x is rational and nonzero, then $f_r(x)=1/(q^r)$ where $x=p/q$

My thought: Since $r\ge1$, I know that $1/(q^r)\le1/q$, so I want to find $\delta>0$ such that $\epsilon\gt |x|=|p/q|\ge|1/q|\ge|1/(q^r)|$.

Thus, I want $|x-\alpha|<\delta$ to imply that $|x|\lt\epsilon$. Since $|x|-|\alpha|\le|x-\alpha|\lt \delta$, I have $|x|\lt\delta+|\alpha|$. To get $|x|\lt\epsilon$, I need $\delta+|\alpha|\le\epsilon$, so I will let $\delta=|\epsilon-|\alpha||$

Testing if this would work: If $|x-\alpha|\lt\delta$ and $x=p/q$, then $|x|-|\alpha|\le|x-\alpha|\lt|\epsilon-|\alpha||$.

At this point, I can't say that $|x|\lt\epsilon$ because of the extra set of absolute values around $|\epsilon-|\alpha||$, but I can't get rid of that absolute value since, in that case, $\delta$ could easily be less than 0.

Thoughts?

Comment: You've made an excellent start: you've reduced the problem to showing that for any irrational $\alpha$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $1/q < \epsilon$ whenever $|p/q-\alpha|<\delta$. Equivalent is the contrapositive: there exists $\delta>0$ such that$|p/q-\alpha|\ge\delta$ whenever $1/q\ge\epsilon$. But there aren't many $q$ satisfying that latter inequality, right? And for each such $q$, there are only a few $p$ that might be worrisome. And you can tailor your $\delta$ to exclude any finite number of worrisome fractions....

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this as a comment (need 50p). But I think you should consider a sequence of rationals approaching any irrational number and study f:s values at these points.

Comment: My teacher said something along these lines and I didn't quite get it. Is this based off the fact that if a convergent sequence converges to a limit, any infinite subsequence converges to the same limit?

Comment: This is related but not what we want. If you want to prove continuity using the sequential criterion, you need to show convergence of the function on any sequence converging to the point. Considering sequences of rationals is not enough.

Comment: Yes a function is continous at c iff for every conv. sequence xn whith limit c f (xn) -> f (c). Since any irrational sequence with limit at any irrational point c f converges to f (c). We would like to examine how f acts at irrational sequences and later try to make a general statement. Try to write $\sqrt (2)$ in Q up to some accuracy and study the values of f at these points.

Comment: Sould ofc. be any rational sequence with a limit at some irrational number c.

Comment: ahjerp, do you have a link to a source that has this statement about continuity & convergent subsequences? I'm having trouble finding it in my book and on Google.

Comment: It is pretty straight forward proving this theorem, but yeah sure, you can find it at Stephen Abbott - Understanding analysis, theorem 4.3.2. or Baby Rudin somewhere at chapter 4.